# Compose nested aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im sorry for any english misstake.

i hope that someone can help me.

Supose that i have the following mapping to my index:

```
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "nestedOBJField": {
        "type": "nested",
        "index": true
      },
       "keywordField": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is possible to use the composite feature with nested fields?

It will be very handful if  i can do something like this:

```
GET /test-index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "TestAgg": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "keyWordFieldAgg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "keyWordField"
              }
            },
           {
            "nestedFieldAgg": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "nestedOBJField.attribute"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this aproach is returning a several number of errors.

I will appreciate a lot if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Property nestedOBJField is of data type "nested" and property keyWordField is keyword type and at same level as  nestedOBJField.

To use nested fields in aggregation , you need to use [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) but then all sources in composite aggegation must be of type nested. This [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/73566) can tell more about it.

You can use following work arounds.

1. Move keyWordField  inside nested object in your documents.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "nestedOBJField": {
        "type": "nested",        
        "properties":{
              "keywordField": {
              "type": "keyword"
             }
         }
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Document**

```
{
    "nestedOBJField":[
      {
          "attribute":"1",
          "age":1,
           "keywordField":"xyz"
      },
      {
          "attribute":"2",
          "age":2,
           "keywordField":"xyz"
      }
    ]
}
```

**Query**

```
"aggs": {
    "TestAgg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "nestedOBJField"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "composite": {
            "size": 10000,
            "sources": [
              {
                "nestedFieldAgg": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "nestedOBJField.attribute.keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "a":{
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "nestedOBJField.keywordField.keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Moving your field inside nested property will mean data duplication , updating data in all nested documents.

2. Using terms aggregation - pagination will be an issue in this case

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "TestAgg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "nestedOBJField"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "nestedOBJField.attribute.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "back_to_parent": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "keywords": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "keywordField.keyword",
                    "size": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```